# Memoir won't create huge document

Tags: memoir, posters

I am trying to use `memoir`'s page features to create a *huge* document (a poster).

It will be one of those fancy science fair presentation boards that consists of two 36in*48in stacked against each other, both in landscape orientation. So my document will be 72in*48in.

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
%% The stock paper size
\setstocksize{72in}{48in}

%% The 'real' page size
\settrimmedsize{72in}{48in}{*}

%% The stock paper will be trimmed 3mm from the
%% top edge and 3mm from the left edge
%\settrims{3mm}{3mm}

%% Spine and trim page margins from main typeblock
\setlrmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}

%% Top and bottom page margins from main typeblock
\setulmarginsandblock{1.4in}{20mm}{*}

%% Header occupies height of a single line;
%% Bottom edge of footer is 7mm from bottom edge
%% of typeblock
%\setheadfoot{\baselineskip}{7mm}

%% Bottom edge of header is 7mm from top edge of
%% typeblock
%\setlength\headsep{7mm}

%% Apply and enforce layout
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{multicols}{4}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Is this a limitation of `memoir`? The class works perfectly for smaller posters. If so, what are some workarounds? `geometry`, I believe, doesn't work too well.

EDIT:
Try adding some `multicol`. That's what I meant.

Comment: I get a PDF and no error from the example document.

Comment: My PDF comes out approx. the correct dimensions, as well. Is the problem that they are not exactly correct?

Comment: @egreg @cfr Try adding `multicol` in the doc.

Comment: The maximum dimension that TeX can manage is about 226in; since 72*4=288, there's no hope of using four columns. Of course you can scale down your poster to a manageable dimension and then print a scaled up rendering. You won't be using 10pt size on such a huge panel, will you?

Comment: @egreg Could Lua-/XeTeX work?

Comment: @SimonKuang No, they have the same size limitation.

Comment: @egreg By the way, this is just sample stuff. The real poster has cool frame stuff and big letters.

Comment: Confused... why would each column be 72in? Wouldn't it need to be half that?

Comment: @egreg That sucks. Is there any workaround?

Comment: @SimonKuang I already told you.

Comment: @SimonKuang Of course it's nonsense to use 72in as page height if the height you want is 36in. If the letters are big, what's the problem in scaling it up? I'd say you want `\setstocksize{48in}{36in}`

Comment: @egreg for the scaling solution would the OP want to use an optical font size corresponding to the intended actual size?

Comment: @jlovegren Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The maximum length managed by TeX is 16383.99998pt, which corresponds to 226.71in (575.83cm). If you have a big sheet 72 inch high, then four columns would require typesetting a 288 inch high box, which is too much. TeX would complain at the time the columns are being split, because it is able to build a box with any dimension (subject only to memory limitations), but it can't operate on a box that exceeds the maximum length.

The best strategy in this case is to build a scaled down version. Scaling by half each dimension could be enough; when printing, just scale up. Also the fonts will be scaled up, so you need to keep this into account; but nobody would produce a 72⨉48 inch poster with a font size at 10pt. If you double the size in print, you'd automatically get a 20pt font. If that's not what you want, just make a balance (but I'd say that 20pt is a bare minimum for such a poster).

Comment: Thank you. By the way, the 10pt was just a test (as evidenced by the `lipsum`ing. MWE.). The real poster is 24pt. I'll just scale a raster when it's printing time.