# tikzpicture Dimension too large!

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a large diagram which I have implemented in TikZ, currently the size is 16042 × 457. If I try to add more nodes and extend the diagram horizontally, I get the Dimension too large! error and cannot compile the document. Is there a way to go around this and make the diagram larger?

I am aware that I am not providing a MWE but it is tricky as the diagram has about 300 nodes, and without them I cannot replicate the error.

Edit: here is a sample of code which gives this error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=\maxdimen,paperheight=\maxdimen]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] at (0, 0) {tikz rectangle};

\node[draw] at (600, 0) {tikz circle};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Change 600 to 500 or less, and the error disappears.

Comment: Maybe you can divide all dimensions by 10 and put the whole tikzpicture within a \scalebox{10}{...} ? Not sure it will work though. Also, I'm curious which class of document you are working on that fits such a big picture.

Comment: It is a modified \documentclass{article}.

Comment: You can surely add an example that is just of the critical size without using 300 nodes, can't you?

Comment: You are right, now added.

Comment: I find that @Arnaud's suggestion works: `\scalebox{2}{\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm,y=5mm]
\node[draw] at (0, 0) {tikz rectangle};

\node[draw] at (600, 0) {tikz circle};

\end{tikzpicture}}`

Comment: It does indeed work, however in my case I would need to shrink all fonts and shape sizes too. If there is no "proper" way to do it, I will use it.

Comment: You can use `\scalebox{2}{\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm,y=5mm,nodes={scale=1/2,transform shape}]
\node[draw] at (0, 0) {tikz rectangle};

\node[draw] at (600, 0) {tikz circle};

\end{tikzpicture}}` to shrink the nodes automatically. If you mean by "proper way" to circumvent the TeX limits on the maximal dimension once and for all, I think this would require to rewrite TeX.

Comment: Ah, and you may want to use something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515305/194703) to transform the line widths, too.

Comment: So is this limit to the figure size of tikz set in stone then? How was it chosen?

Comment: @Grants The limits of TikZ are the same as those of TeX...

Comment: @Grants Max length: 16383.99998pt (5.75832m) ! You second node is at `(600cm,0cm)` = (6m, 0m) !

Answer (score 3):

`\maxdimen` is the largest legal `<dimen>` that supported by TeX-dimensions (±16383.99999pt).

According to `pgfmanual 56.1 Fixed Point Arithmetic Library Overview`

> In addition the range of values that can be computed is very small: ±16383.99999. Conversely, the fp package has a reasonably high accuracy, and can perform computations over a wide range of values (approximately
> ±9.999 × 1017),

while for dimensions:

> **The pgf mathematical engine** will still be used to evaluate lengths, such as 10pt or 3em, so **it is not possible for an length to exceed the range of values supported by TEX-dimensions (±16383.99999pt)**,
> even though the resulting expression is within the range of fp. So, for example, **one can calculate 3cm*10000, but not 3*10000cm**.

Ti*k*Z library `fpu` is like `fp` but have higher accuracy and is faster and more efficient. So we can do some test with `fpu`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}

\begin{document}

\pgfset{fpu, fpu/output format=fixed}
\pgfmathparse{1cm * 600}
\begin{tabular}{rcl}
  \verb|\maxdimen| & is & \the\maxdimen.\\
  600cm & is & \pgfmathresult pt.
\end{tabular}
% \pgfmathparse{600cm} % error!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So there is no way to make something larger than 16383.99999pt by 16383.99999pt?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to shrink your fonts or dimensions, TikZ doesn't use floating point numbers, so, when you don't set units it can overflow.

By setting a `x` and `y` dimensional value to the units, it will allow to work just fine without shrinking your fonts.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=\maxdimen,paperheight=\maxdimen]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.2cm, y=0.2cm]
\node[draw] at (0, 0) {tikz rectangle};

\node[draw] at (600, 0) {tikz circle};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: right side]
[image: left side]

Comment: Keep in mind that you are just moving the goalpost. TikZ has this fundamental limit of how large a number it can handle.

Comment: But this changes the sizes of my nodes, too?

Comment: It defines a width and height for x and y. So, when you say `(3,2)` it means `(0.6cm. 0.4cm)` if `x=0.2 y=0.2`.

Comment: Like @Paul Gaborit said on his comment, there is a hard limit on the maximum height and width... https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151903/120176